# No audio and video in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have Windows 8 Pro x64, and I don't have sound, but when I install Windows 8 Release Preview x64 sound starts working. I have an HP 620 laptop, IDT High-Definition (HD) Audio Driver, Mobile Intel(r) 4 Series Express chipset family graphics.

What's the problem and how can I get sound working in Windows 8 RTM?

Comment: You need to update your sound drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The programs that control your computer's devices are called drivers.

On the HP website they do not have drivers for Windows 8. You will need to get the drivers from the people who made the individual components of your system.

As per [this](http://www.eightforums.com/hardware-drivers/6378-idt-hd-audio-not-working.html) forum post, your audio should be available from [here](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Home.aspx).

I would also encourage you to perform a Windows update by searching for `PC settings` in the from the search bar. You may find more updates for your computer.
[image: Windows 8 Update]